# Does react native template support without using typescript like on react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am currently studying react native with a redux toolkit. Right now I am on the stage of installing react native with a template of redux toolkit. My concern is, does react native support redux toolkit without the template of typescript?

React Native Document: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

**npx react-native init AwesomeTSProject --template react-native-template-typescript**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following link.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#getting-started-with-typescript